# Entity Data Model Wizard closes after selecting connection and not proceeding to next stage(table/sp selection)

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, edmx, vs-community-edition

I know this is kind of weired issue, but I'm unable to find a fix after searching for it.

In VS2015, add new 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model' process, After selecting the data connection Entity Data Model Wizard gets closed instead of proceeding to next stage(table/sp selection).

Does anyone had similar issue and can help me fix this? I've restarted VS, my machine too, no change.

I'm using:
Visual Studio community 2015, Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3,
MySql Connector 6.9.9

Comment: I've got the solution, I've deleted the MySql Connector(using MySQL Installer) and added it again and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the solution, I've removed the MySql Connector(using MySQL Installer) and added it again and it works now.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, what version did you install ?

Comment: Thank you so much, spent a while trying to figure this out. To everyone out there, you MUST have the .NET connector installed on your dev box, having the .dlls in your project dir is not enough.